# download a file in inbox without opening a new tab in java gwt

Tags: java, gwt, attachment

i have developed an gwt project with java which is something like a web mail.i want to download an attached file in a mail and for this i make a url and use com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(url,"_blank", ""); after running this a tab opens and download dialog appears and tab closes but i want to show save download dialog without opening and closing the new tab. i want to have somthing like what gamil or ymail do while downloading attachments.
here is my code:

```
 `final String url= "fetchAttachment.service?index="
        + mailData.getId().trim()
        + "&&"
        + "mailboxUid="
        + URL.encodeComponent(mailData
        .getMailBoxUid())
        + "&&"
        + "attachmentIndex="
    + mailData.getAttachments().get(i)
        .getIndex();
      CutLabel tempLabel = new CutLabel(attachemnts
     .get(i).getFileName(), 100);
      Window.open(url, "_blank", "");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Window.open(url, "myWindow", "");
```